# Want to edit 'Default New Form' for list but I don't get a ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, custom-form, list-form

I have recently created a list for issues and some fields in this list shouldn't be visible when a user wants to create a new ticket.

I don't have SP Designer, InfoPath or Visual Studio available but I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHnXhO0fIoI) video that provides a way to create custom forms without using any of the above mentioned software since I'm able to add Site Assets without using SP Designer.

However, when I try to do the same actions and go to the list and click on Form Web Parts>Default New Form I don't get the ribbon which would allow me to create the custom form for my list. I have added a screenshot below of my site without the ribbon, in the video this happens at [3:23](https://youtu.be/vHnXhO0fIoI?t=3m23s)

[image: Default New Form - No Ribbon]

Does anyone know why I'm not getting a ribbon here and how I would be able to get the ribbon so I can create my custom form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the default forms in SharePoint Online, you need to click Settings button in the top right corner and click “Edit page”.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible anymore without any additional tools, [SharePoint Designer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491) is an easy (and free) tool to use if you're prepared to play with the code. I did however find this [blog](https://today.collab365.community/story/how-can-i-customize-list-forms-in-sharepoint-online/) post which gives a few options for you to explore.

Comment: SP Designer isn't available for download in my company approved software. I do have a personal laptop but I'm unable to use designer on this because if I access SP from my worklaptop, I am automatically logged in using data on the PC. I don't know and have no way of learning my password. I will take a look at the blog post later today or early tomorrow.

Comment: You might be able to use Virto Forms Designer if you have an app catalog site, I think this will be the answer you're looking for. Just import this [app](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa104380136?src=office&corrid=67f0a1f5-0b7f-49f6-b676-74b585502066&omexanonuid=01260211-cdd5-44b3-bc64-94a6fc0d07db) into the SharePoint app catalog